# Is there a better solution to R CMD javareconf -e?

Tags: python, r, rpy2, rjava

I am currently working on a project that aims to offer an application either for vanilla using - by running just the implemented features and algorithms - and also easy to extend in order to help another researchers with a "just plug your extra code here" architecture.

I'm using Electron Python-backended that in turn also communicates with R using the **rpy2** library.
The problem is that one of the R libraries my Python code needs to load, uses rJava, and the only way I found to make the syntax `rpackages.importr('rJava')` work, was, before running the Python script, export some R/Java variables (I think it does that) with the command `R CMD javareconf -e`, then it works fine on Ubuntu.

I briefly tested this solution also on Windows and it didn't work. So I want to know how can I solve it, if there is another way.

In the Linux scenario, do you think running the npm start (for the whole Electron app) preceded by the R CMD command would work? Isn't there a better solution for this?

I also was thinking about using a Docker container, but I fear this would make it harder for another researchers plug their code into the App (if an external library was needed, for example).

The error without using `R CMD javareconf -e` is this:

```
...............
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/packages.py", line 483, in importr
    env = _get_namespace(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/conversion.py", line 40, in _
    cdata = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rpy2/rinterface.py", line 791, in __call__
    raise embedded.RRuntimeError(_rinterface._geterrmessage())
rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded.RRuntimeError: Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/home/thispc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I already tried `~$sudo R CMD javareconf`

Answer (score 0):

R seems to be installed in an unconventional location. May the linker cannot find it. Does setting the environment variables as suggested in the output of the following command help ?

```
python -m rpy2.situation LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Using the command `~$ python3 -m rpy2.situation LD_LIBRARY_PATH ` gives following output: `/usr/lib/R/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server` but it didn't solve the problem. I think it's something with R/Java, since other packages load just fine.

Comment: Did you run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/R/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server` to set up the environment in which Python+rpy2 will run ? (you run `export ...` right before starting python, in the same shell).

Comment: Oh, sorry. 

Ok, so I ran 
`~$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/R/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server`

Then started a python3 shell and tried to import rJava:
`>>> import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages`
`>>> rpackages.importr('rJava')`

The result:
(some traceback error and...) 
` raise LibraryError('The symbol ' + rname +
rpy2.robjects.packages.LibraryError: The symbol .env in the package "rJava" is conflicting with a Python object attribute`

Answer (score 0):

`lang-js R CMD javareconf -e` cannot be used on Windows. The solution which also overcomes the error message @Collombelli mentions:

```js
rpy2.robjects.packages.LibraryError: The symbol .env in the package "rJava" is conflicting with a Python object attribute
```

Is the below code:

```js
rJava = importr('rJava', robject_translations={'.env': '__env'})
```

Credit to M Sellwood